# Is this new job a scam?

Tags: scams, fraud, cryptocurrency

Hi so I was applying for online jobs and randomly received an email for a Personal Assistant job from JRN Financial Solutions, everything went by super quick and I got the job which I don't feel I was qualified for. I signed the contract and did my first day which I had to create a word letter for investing in Bitcoin. This is the second day and they want me to create a brochure within a week for bitcoin and their website but they also want to send me 1000-3000CAD to purchase bitcoin and receive a 350 dollar commission, they have my bank account number but nothing has been done yet, I can't find anything out about the company besides the website. Is this a scam?

Comment: It's a scam.  Once you send them bitcoin, the money they sent you gets pulled back, but the money you spent is gone.  Cut off all contact with these people and get a new bank account; the one you gave them the information for is compromised.

Comment: Okay thank you, I just opened a brand new account to be safe and put 20 dollars in it, should I still be worried?

Comment: YES YOU SHOULD BE WORRIED. STOP TALKING TO SCAMMERS. The 3000CAD is stolen. You will be used to buy BTC and send it back. When the theft of the 3000CAD and your 350CAD commission is found, your bank will take the money back. You will lose that money from YOUR account. Even if the account has only 20 in it, the bank will still come after you to pay the difference.

Comment: Close your old account.  You should probably call your bank and explain the situation so that they can mark it as 'compromised' and ensure that no more transactions occur against it.  And be aware that you're now on the 'susceptible to scams' list, so you'll get a lot of solicitations for other scams.  Any auto-pay bills you might have will need to be moved to the new account.

Comment: Also you can now expect either or both of a) the scammers calling you pretending to be the FBI / a law firm / your bank and asking you to pay money to "go after the scammers", and/or b) the scammers calling you and threatening to report you to the police / the FBI etc unless you pay them money. Basically, treat any new unsolicited contacts with an extreme level of scepticism.

Comment: It is a scam. Whatever money they put into your account is stolen and will disappear into thin air - today, next week, or in six months time. Nothing you can do to stop it because the money is stolen. However, any money that _you_ send out is your money and it’s gone and your bank will ask you to pay for it. If they send you $3,000 and you send $2,650 in Bitcoin your bank account will be at minus $2,650. Whatever happens, do NOT send any money to anyone because that money will be gone to the scammer, and neither police nor your bank can help you.